# how to share the global variable between several processes with Django

Tags: django

I develop one app with Django framework and deploy it on ubuntu using uwsgi and nginx.

If nginx boot two worker processes, these processes will load django app code in two memory areas. If we use global variable `G` in views.py, then the change for `G` in one HTTP request may be invisible to another HTTP request.

How to share global information between different processes with Django ?

Comment: Isn't that what a database is for? :-)

Comment: What is the global variable even for? why do you need it?

Comment: Surely it's a *good* thing that variables aren't shared? Otherwise one user would be able to modify things for everyone.

Comment: Is there any better solution ? @solarissmoke

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to achieve here. If there is information that multiple processes need to read/write, then it should be in the database - that is what a database is for. Having some kind of magic global that different processes can edit is just dangerous, even it it were possible.

Comment: There is a view function need to request third-party website for one token. I use a global dict to store the token for avoiding request the third-party website frequently. @Sayse

Comment: Surely you can just store it in the database.

Comment: got it, thank you @solarissmoke

Comment: It's not the user that modify the shared variable, it's the program modify the shared variable for all users every 2 hours. thank you @DanielRoseman

Comment: Even I am looking for this solution. Can we use singleton for this?
this is really important features , there are so many use cases where we want to share handful of variables to all programs , to avoid db hits or to avoid using cache etc...
Programming languages like Java does have it we use this all the time, so looking something similar